# python script for copy and sorting the color_images by giving input vale as the product numbers same as json and grey images in the below program

Tags: python, json

copy and sort all(color images, grey images, and JSON) together for further process.
I have color image files with a different name. like folder name is XYZ inside the folder files are like this
965_0000000005_0000000001_color_20210518174648.jpg....
965_0000000005_0000000002_color_20211105153826.jpg
But after copying, the files into the color_images folder want to rename the file names for color images.
965_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153826.jpg (new file name)
In file name
0000000005-0000000001_color_20211105153826.jpg(remove _color)
965_0000000005_0000000001_20211105153826.jpg

sort files in a new folder

```
20220628    (new folder is todays date))
  20220628_RAV4_2_anomaly
    color_images    (Color images only in this folder because files 
                                  names are defined_0000000005_)
    grey_images
    json
  20220628_RAV4_3_anomaly 
     grey_images
     json
 20220628_RAV4_4_anomaly
    grey_images
    json
```

please help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much in advanced

code

```
import os
import shutil
from datetime import date

  def gen_range(text):
     start, end = [int(i) for i in text.split("-")]
     return list(range(start,end))

  def get_user_input():
     nums = input("Enter the product numbers - example: (123;135;561-568;12)\n")
    if ";" in nums:
        values = []
        for value in [i for i in nums.split(';')]:
        if "-" in value:
            values += gen_range(value)
        else:
            values.append(value)
    elif nums.isdigit():
        values = [int(nums)]
     elif "-" in nums:
        values = gen_range(nums)
     else:
         raise ValueError
     return list(map(str,values))

def get_input_values():
     while True:
         nums = get_user_input()
         product = input("Enter product name: ")
         status = input("Enter the product status\nEnter 0 for OK\nEnter 1 for 
   NG\nEnter other for others\n")
          d = {"numbers": nums, "status": status, "product": product}
          print(d)
         correct = input("Is the above information correct? yes/no: ")
         if correct == "yes":
             return d

  def output_path(filename, status, product, outpaths):
      today = "".join(str(date.today()).split("-"))
      parts = filename.split("_")
     if parts[1] in outpaths:
         num = outpaths[parts[1]]
    else:
         num = "3"
         outpaths[parts[1]] = num
     if status == "0":
          status = "anomaly"
    else:
         status = "nomaly"
        subdir = "_".join([today, product, str(num), status])
if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == ".json":
    path = os.path.join(today, subdir, "json")
else:
    path = os.path.join(today, subdir, "grey_images")

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
return os.path.join(path,filename)

def copyfiles(numbers=None, status=None, product=None):
unused = numbers[:]
data = os.walk(os.path.normcase('./'))
outpaths = {"0000000005": "2", "0000000011": "4"}
for root, _, files in data:
    for filename in files:
        part = filename.split('_')[0]
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if part in numbers and ext.lower() in [".json",".jpeg",".jpg"]:
            if part in unused:
                unused.remove(part)
            origin = os.path.join(root, filename)
            dest = output_path(filename, status, product, outpaths)
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(origin, dest)
                print(f"OK==>No {filename} has been copied.")
            except:
                print(f"NG==>No {part} failed to copy")
for number in unused:
    print(f"NG==>No {number} does not exist")



if __name__ == "__main__":
     params = get_input_values()
     copyfiles(**params)
```

Comment: @alexpdev Here I have posted new questions its similar to before.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768125/copy-and-sort-multiple-jpeg-files-and-json-files-in-one-folder-to-another-folder?noredirect=1#comment128532203_72768125

Comment: @alexpdev I have updated my question please check.

Comment: I honestly can't make sense of the title of your question. For a start, remove "in the below program", because that's implied that details follow. This trend persists. You're also asking about a problem, but what exactly is the problem? Where are you stuck? Just dumping your homework here for someone else to work on is not the base of a good question. Please read [ask], which explains how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the output path for any images if that image filename contains the word 'color' in it.

For example:

```
import os
import shutil
from datetime import date

def gen_range(text):
    start, end = [int(i) for i in text.split("-")]
    return list(range(start,end))

def get_user_input():
    nums = input("Enter the product numbers - example: (123;135;561-568;12)\n")
    if ";" in nums:
        values = []
        for value in [i for i in nums.split(';')]:
            if "-" in value:
                values += gen_range(value)
            else:
                values.append(value)
    elif nums.isdigit():
        values = [int(nums)]
    elif "-" in nums:
        values = gen_range(nums)
    else:
         raise ValueError
    return list(map(str,values))

def get_input_values():
    while True:
        nums = get_user_input()
        product = input("Enter product name: ")
        status = input("Enter the product status\nEnter 0 for OK\nEnter 1 for NG\nEnter other for others\n")
        d = {"numbers": nums, "status": status, "product": product}
        print(" ".join([f"{k}: {v};" for k,v in d.items()]))
        correct = input("Is the above information correct? yes/no: ")
        if correct == "yes":
            return d


class OutFactory:

    def __init__(self, numbers=None, status=None, product=None):
        self.today = "".join(str(date.today()).split("-"))
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.status = self.get_status(status)
        self.product = product
        self.outpaths = {"0000000005": "2", "0000000011": "4"}

    def get_status(self, status):
        if status == "0":
            return "anomaly"
        return "nomaly"

    def get_num(self, part):
        if part not in self.outpaths:
            self.outpaths[part] = "3"
        return self.outpaths[part]

    def gen_output(self, path):
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
        parent = os.path.split(dirname)[1]
        number = parent.split("_")[0]
        parts = filename.split("_")
        if number in self.numbers:
            return self.color_dir(filename, number)
        elif parts[0] in self.numbers:
            return self.json_dir(filename, parts)
        return None

    def color_dir(self, filename, number):
        filename = filename.replace("-","_")
        parts = filename.split("_")
        num = self.get_num(parts[0])
        if "color" not in parts:
            parts = [num] + parts
            filename = '_'.join(parts)
            return self.json_dir(filename, parts)
        parts.remove("color")
        filename = '_'.join([number] + parts)
        subdir = "_".join([self.today, self.product, str(num), self.status])
        final = os.path.join(self.today, subdir, "color_images")
        if not os.path.exists(final):
            os.makedirs(final)
        return os.path.join(final, filename)

    def json_dir(self, filename, parts):
        num = self.get_num(parts[1])
        subdir = "_".join([self.today, self.product, str(num), self.status])
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()
        path = None
        if ".json" in extension:
            path = os.path.join(self.today, subdir, "json")
        elif ".jpg" in extension:
            if "color" not in filename:
                path = os.path.join(self.today, subdir, "grey_images")
            else:
                partials = filename.split("_")
                if "color" in partials:
                    partials.remove("color")
                filename = "_".join(partials)
                path = os.path.join(self.today, subdir, "color_images")
        if not path:
            return None
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        return os.path.join(path,filename)


def copyfiles(factory):
    data = os.walk(os.path.normcase('./'))
    for root, _, files in data:
        for filename in files:
            origin = os.path.join(root, filename)
            output = factory.gen_output(origin)
            if output:
                try:
                    shutil.copyfile(origin, output)
                    print(f"OK==>No {output} has been copied.")
                except:
                    print(f"NG==>No {origin} failed to copy")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     params = get_input_values()
     outfactory = OutFactory(**params)
     copyfiles(outfactory)
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X3kC.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MqQA.png)

Comment: @yuna I am in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245955/discussion-between-alexpdev-and-yuna

Comment: please check the chat.

Comment: Please check the screenshots before and after.
There are no changes.
Couldn't create the color_images folder and the "color" files were also copied into the grey_images folder.

Comment: @yuna  try the program now

Comment: @yuna your welcome sorry I couldnt do more

Comment: No worries.  Once again thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960987/python-zipping-the-subfolders-including-inside-the-data#comment128866909_72960987
could you please answer the new question?